# Problems with the Pitchi Poy Rig

Tags: rigging

[image]Primary

I am having difficulty parenting an armature to a mesh.

Secondary

I wonder if someone could please help me. I am trying to skin a model with the pitchi poy rig. I first made a simple rig to test the model and it parents and deforms just fine with this test rig. No problem. So, I added the pitchi poy rig, lined up all the bones and then generated the rig. The controller works fine with the green deformation bones. **See the picture above, everything deforms fine**! However, when I try to parent the rig to the model, nothing happens. I have tried parenting the model with the rig, as shown in both Mark Edwards and the Pitchi Poy videos to no effect. They use a simple armature deform and then, with the bones selected, use weight paint to assign automatic weights from the bones.

I've tried parenting the model to the rig using automatic weights. Nothing. I know how to parent a rig, selecting the model first and then the rig etc etc. It worked OK with this mesh and my test rig, but I cannot see why I cannot get the pitchi poy rig to parent with my model while at the same time, the pitchi poy controllers work just fine with the green deformation bones. I must be missing something real stupid, but I cannot see what, so if anybody knows what I am doing wrong, I would be so grateful if they could let me know before I go completely mad! I really have tried and tried before posting here! By the way, I have also looked on Google etc for an answer, but so far I have failed to find a solution! Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to BSE.  Please place an screen capture image in your question.  Since the number of images you may place may be limited you might be wise to compose one image from separate screen captures with GIMP or comparable.  Be sure to show the outliner with the detail of the expected rig being the parent to the expected mesh.  I am going to make a quick edit of your question because IMHOIIHO the long paragraph is difficult to read.  Some of what you wrote is difficult to understand.

Comment: Is there any chance you can [include project files](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) and trim down the information to only what we will need to help you?

Comment: This could be a simple matter of applying scale and rotation to both the Armature and the Body Mesh before attempting to perform the Auto Weighted Parent, have you tried this yet?

Comment: Thanks Rick. Yes, I applied scale & rotation to the armature and mesh. Maybe, the question I should've asked was can anyone give me a step by step way you parent a mesh to a pitchi poy rig i.e. the idiot's guide, because I am sure I am missing something … Like I said the Controller and deformation bones work great. It's just that I can't seem to get the mesh and the green deformation bones to parent. Sorry I've got to go out now, I'll put up screen capture tomorrow, but I doubt if it'll show anything other than the deformation bones and controller work … do keep the suggestions coming, thanks!

Comment: You can add an image by editing your question.  Above the question the tool bar has icons. Click the 6th icon which looks like a mountain in a frame.

Comment: Thanks, atomicbezierslinger …  the enable eye is turned on … I've been trying the parenting and weight painting over and over again, but the problem is that everything is going fine right up to the point of parenting the mesh to the deformed bones rig … I just can't get the rig to parent the mesh … I'll put up a screen dump of just before the parenting process (when I've worked out how to do that), so that you can see the generated rig moves with the controller just fine, but nothing happens when I try to parent them … any ideas why gratefully received!

Comment: The enabled eye is active, the alignment is correct … the green bones deform correctly, as expected … it just won't parent with the mesh!

Comment: You have stated the [green bones deform correctly. Do you mean the green bones [move and rotate]?  The word deform is more often used with the mesh, and more rarely with bones IMHOIIHO. Others can disagree.  I would change the language above if you feel it would improve the explanation. Most of the time when people parent an armature to a mesh, the bones are inside the corresponding parts of the mesh that each bone controls.  Why is your armature outside the mesh?

Comment: Examine the mesh in weight paint mode.  See if clicking on each vertex group shows the red influence color for the mesh.  Please see this video tutorial   .......      https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GvG39bGEsKI   .... In the proposed answer below do you see how the bones are inside the mesh.  This could be better proven by 2 or 3 images of top side and front.

Comment: Thanks all for the help! The screen dump was meant to show how I could move the deform bones about with the controller. The problem was I couldn't parent the deform bones to the mesh, even though I'm doing everything right. Honest! Today, I tried rigging with a different mesh. The green pitchi poy deform bones parented first time with this new mesh. Could something be wrong with the first mesh? At first glance, this new mesh is deforming fine. The pitchi p. face rig's brilliant. BTW, I always look here if I've a problem and nearly always find an answer, so thanks to all for past help I've had!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that when you create the parent child relationship the bones are within the mesh and the bones are selected last.

[image]

Make sure that all bones have their deform check box ... checked active.

In the modifiers pane inspect the armature modifier.  The enable eye icon should be active.  It can be turned off and on.  If is turned off it will have no effect.

[image]

You can also delete the armature modifier and parent it again.  Make sure to view the armature and the mesh from 3 angles top, front and side to make sure the alignment is correct.  If you have not done much weight painting do not hesitate to delete the armature modifier and parent again.